# Usage of NOT operator in #define directives in C programming

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have defined macros as below.

```
#define FALSE   0
#define TRUE    (!FALSE)
```

What will be the data-type of `TRUE` and `FALSE`? What literal value does `TRUE` take after preprocessing? Is it compiler dependent? Why?

Comment: This might not be relevant, and you probably already know this, but if you need boolean types you can `#include <stdbool.h>` and use `false` and `true` "natively" as long as your compiler/code support C99 and above.

Comment: You definitively should use the standard types. Such custom defines/enums/etc. are more than obsolete and possibly dangerous. `_Bool` e.g. might use a smaller variable than `int` and any assignment to `_Bool` will be converted to `0` or `1` (instead of `0` / not `0`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`#define` preprocessor directive (macros) are meant to do *textual replacement*. It will replace all occurrence of `FALSE` to `0` and `TRUE` to `!0` that essentially gets evaluated to `1`. So, the resultant data type will be same as `0` and `1`. i.e.,  integer.

Regarding the usage of `!` operator, it always produces a result of type `int`.

Quoting the `C11` standard, chapter §6.5.3.3 (*emphasis mine*)

> The result of the logical negation operator `!` is 0 if the value of its operand compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand compares equal to 0. **The result has type `int`**. [...]

Comment: I really hate that legacy crap in C. I was 100% sure `!` yields `_Bool` since C99, but you proved me wrong. Thanks for that.

Comment: @Olaf Thanks. :-) Happy to be of help. :)

Answer (score -2):

At the time of preprocessing, macros are replaced with text.
`FALSE` will be replace by 0, and `TRUE` will be replaced by 1.

Comment: No, `TRUE` will be replaced by `(!0)`. The compiler will then (probably) replace it internally with `1`.